# how to convert the image back to jpg format converted using file_get_contents() in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, base64, encode

```
$bin_string = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]); // image reading
$hex_string = base64_encode($bin_string); // encoded image
```

Saving into database and then retrieving back...

```
$decoded= base64_decode($message); // decoded image....
```

In HTML:

```
<?php header("Content-Length: " . strlen($decoded));
header('Content-Type: image/png'); ?>
<?php echo $decoded ?>
```

But this is not working.... what else is needed?
Here is the output of base64_encode($bin_string) :
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

Comment: sorry but tried with jpg too...still not working....not able to understand what is the problem....as I am using this in codeigniter, If i use the above code in controller, it works fine. but if i try the same in view, it does not work....

Comment: What is *not working*?

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

`$_FILES["file"]["name"]` contains only name of uploaded file. Real temporary path of uploaded file on your server is stored in `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`.

```
$bin_string = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

**2)**

There can be some invisible character printed out before or after the image.

Please ensure that `<?php` is the first thing on the first row of your file and, for simplicity, remove all other `<?php` and `?>`, including the last one. You can add `die;` on the last row to end the script to ensure that nothing else is added to the end of image.

Comment: I have used the following method so no issue with this : move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: or provide me any suitable method to convert image into string to store into db and  then to restore it again...

Comment: Now you are saving all uploaded files permanently to current directory. Do you have permission to write into the directory? What is stored in DB (can help to find out if problem is in saving or retrieving)?

Comment: yes, it is getting written correctly.also I am able to get the output correctly from here ...$decoded= base64_decode($message); now the issue is how to display the image further in html after getting the value from $decoded???

Comment: `echo` is sufficent. Please share one of your images in encoded form.

Comment: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/7Q1oUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNA+0KUmVzb2x1dGlvbgAAAAAQAEgAAAABAAEASAAAAAEAAThCSU0EDRhGWCBHbG9iYWwgTGlnaHRpbmcgQW5nbGUAAAAABAAAAHg

Comment: I went through the part of base64 string you provided in comments and discovered that it's not PNG file, but JFIF file.

Comment: sorry that was just incomplete ...now i added the code in encoded form in my question...please check it.

Comment: It's JFIF (JPEG) file. You can't use `Content-Type: image/png` with this file.

Comment: Edited my answer to give you another advice.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution...

simply convert the image using 
$bin_string = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); // image reading

And then for converting string back to image use the following :
" />